# Problem with displaying a modal using PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with the modal system on my website. Now I will provide you some code:

```
MODALS ARE MADE WITH W3.CSS LIB
```

**modal.js (with some debug)**

```js
let modal = null;
let title = null;
let content = null;

$(document).ready(() =>
{
    modal = $('#modal');
    title = $('#modal-title');
    content = $('#modal-content');

    if(modal == null)
    {
        console.log('aa');
    }
    if(title == null)
    {
        console.log('bb');
    }
    if(content == null)
    {
        console.log('cc');
    }
});

function showModal(modalTitle, modalText)
{
    title.text(modalTitle);
    content.text(modalText);
    modal.show();
}

function hideModal()
{
    modal.hide();
}
```

**Modal HTML template**

```html
<div id="modal" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div style="display: block;" class="fir-light-purple">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h2 id="modal-title">{TITLE}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-container">
            <span id="modal-content">{CONTENT}</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="text-align: center" class="fir-light-purple">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h4><button class="w3-button w3-round-medium fir-white" onclick="hideModal();">Dismiss</button><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AlertGenerator.php (a script that displays a modal)**

```php
<?php

//Current modal code
//<div id="modal" class="w3-modal"><div class="w3-modal-content"><div style="display: block;" class="fir-light-purple"><div class="w3-container"><h2 id="modal-title">{TITLE}</h2></div></div><br><div class="w3-container"><span id="modal-content">{CONTENT}</span></div><br><div style="text-align: center" class="fir-light-purple"><div class="w3-container"><h4><button class="w3-button w3-round-medium fir-white" onclick="hideModal();">Dismiss</button><br></div></div></div></div>

/*
Pretty code:

<div id="modal" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div style="display: block;" class="fir-light-purple">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h2 id="modal-title">{TITLE}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-container">
            <span id="modal-content">{CONTENT}</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="text-align: center" class="fir-light-purple">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h4><button class="w3-button w3-round-medium fir-white" onclick="hideModal();">Dismiss</button><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 */

class AlertGenerator
{
    public static function createAlert(string $title, string $content)
    {
        self::validateSession();
        $_SESSION['alert']['title'] = $title;
        $_SESSION['alert']['content'] = $content;
    }

    public static function displayModal()
    {
        echo '<div id="modal" class="w3-modal"><div class="w3-modal-content"><div style="display: block;" class="fir-light-purple"><div class="w3-container"><h2 id="modal-title">{TITLE}</h2></div></div><br><div class="w3-container"><span id="modal-content">{CONTENT}</span></div><br><div style="text-align: center" class="fir-light-purple"><div class="w3-container"><h4><button class="w3-button w3-round-medium fir-white" onclick="hideModal();">Dismiss</button><br></div></div></div></div>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function showAlert()
    {
        self::validateSession();
        if(array_key_exists('alert', $_SESSION))
        {
            if(!array_key_exists('title', $_SESSION['alert']) || !array_key_exists('content', $_SESSION['alert'])) return;

            $title = addslashes($_SESSION['alert']['title']);
            $content = addslashes($_SESSION['alert']['content']);

            if(empty($title) || empty($content)) return;

            echo '<script>showModal("' . $title . '", "' . $content . '");</script>';
        }
    }

    private static function validateSession()
    {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <?php HeadGenerator::generate('Login', true); ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="/includes/js/loginForm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php AlertGenerator::displayModal(); AlertGenerator::showAlert(); NavBarGenerator::defaultNav(); ?>

<div class="w3-container">
    [... website content ...]
</div>

<script>showModal('test', 'test of modal');</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Example usage creates modal only using  at the bottom.

This is an error I receive: `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "text", title is null`

My debug functions in the .js file don't send any output.

**My expectations**

I'd like to make the modal visible right after the showModal(x, y) function.

**Additional notes:**

When modal code is created by a PHP script, the console error mentioned above appears. When I include the modal code manually (commented modal template in the Example usage), a console error doesn't appear.

Does anyone know how can I resolve this issue?

**EDIT ALPHA**

I forgot that I used functions to create < head >. You can be sure that all the required scripts are included.

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand "Example usage creates modal only using at the bottom.". At the bottom of page? Using bottom method?

Comment: At the bottom there is a < script > with showModal() function. And it is creating a modal @loa_in_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `<?php AlertGenerator::displayModal(); AlertGenerator::showAlert();[...]` you get the modal HTML and result of `echo '<script>showModal("' . $title . '", "' . $content . '");</script>';` right next to each other.

When the page loads, the `<script>showModal(...)</script>` part gets run before the page finishes loading. `showModal()` accesses `title` but it's not set yet! `title` is set only after page is loaded, i.e. in jQuery's `$.ready()` callback.

Comment: I used that second function for debugging stuff, and yeah, I didn't think about this. Thanks for the help mate.